# How do I use user input from one editable table and use it for the next table

Tags: r, shiny

I am working on a Shiny app where the user provides inputs in a series of editable tables.  I am using the DataEditR library for this.  See the code below that on what I have tried.

In Table 1 the user provides a list of last names.  Now in Table 2, I would like to show the last names from table 1 from a drop down menu.  This is where I am having issues.  If I give a static list, the code for Table 2 works.  However, when I try to use the unique values of last names from table 1, the code fails.

I know I can just ask the first and last names in the first table - but this is a simple instance of what I am trying to do.  In the actual app, the subsequent table will have columns where the options are limited to data from prior steps.

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong.

Thanks.

Here is the sample code that I am trying.

```
library(shiny)
library(DataEditR)
library(tidyverse)

# Define UI for application
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("simple example")
    
    , actionButton("go_1", "Go")
    , br()
    , dataEditUI("table_1")
    , br()
    , textOutput("msg_1")
    , br()
    , actionButton("go_2", "Go to table 2")
    , br()
    , dataEditUI("table_2")
)

# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  table_1_df <- dataEditServer(
    "table_1"
    , data = eventReactive(input$go_1, {
      data.frame('id'=rep(c(1:5)))
    })
    , title = 'Table 1'
    , hide = TRUE
    , col_edit = FALSE
    , col_names = FALSE
    , col_readonly = c('id')
    , col_bind = c('last_name')
    )

  output$msg_1 <- renderPrint(  str(table_1_df())   )
  
  last_names_list <- eventReactive(input$go_1,{
    unique(table_1_df$last_name)
  })
  
  table_2_df <- dataEditServer(
    "table_2"
    , data = eventReactive(input$go_2, {
      data.frame('id2'=rep(c(1:5)))
    })
    , title = 'Table 1'
    , hide = TRUE
    , col_edit = TRUE
    , col_names = FALSE
    , col_readonly = c('id2')
    , col_bind = c('last_name','first_name')
    , col_options = c(
      'last_name' = list( c('a','b') )   
      #'last_name' = list( last_names_list )
      )
  )

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another from my point of view much cleaner approach would be to simply use `rhandsontable`, which allows a classic build of the Shiny app including the reactive context of `renderRHandsontable()`.

With this you can easily build 2 tables where the values of one table can be used as input for the second table. The whole thing doesn't need any `ActionButtons`, but the changes are transferred automatically.

I hope this approach is suitable for you and your problem is solved.

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)
library(tidyverse)

# Define UI for application
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("simple example")
  , rHandsontableOutput("table_1")
  , br()
  , rHandsontableOutput("table_2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$table_1 <- renderRHandsontable({
    data <- data.frame('id'=c(1:5),
                       'last_name' = "")
    rhandsontable(data = data)
  })
  
  output$table_2 <- renderRHandsontable({
    last_names <- unique(hot_to_r(input$table_1)$last_name)
    known_values <- isolate(hot_to_r(input$table_2))
    if(!is.null(known_values)){
      data <- known_values
    }
    else{
      data <- data.frame('id'=c(1:5),
                         'last_name' = "",
                         'fist_name' = "")
    }
    rhandsontable(data = data, overflow = 'visible')%>%
      hot_col(col = "last_name", type="dropdown",source = last_names)
  })
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks @Christian.  I need to read up a bit on hot_to_r and unique/isolate functions to understand the logic completely but this seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have a small problem in your example but in general a bigger problem with using reactive variables inside of dataEditServer.

The smaller problem you find at the part where you define `last_names_list`. Here you have to make sure that you call the values of `table_1_df()` followed by parenthesis to get the actual values. You already do this correctly in the print statement above. Also, I changed the dependent variable here to `input$go_2`, since this seems to me to be the intended behavior here.

The bigger problem is that the area of the `dataEditServer` in which you set `col_options` is not a reactive context. Therefore you can't actually read `last_names_list` there.

I have now solved the whole thing as follows.
First I pack the whole `dataEditServer` inside an `oberserveEvent` statement, which is dependent on `input$go_2`. This way I get a reactive context, where I can query the values of `last_names_list`. I store them here in the variable `last_names` and use them below as `col_options`.

With this implementation it is now possible to use the values from table 1 as options in table 2. With each click on the button `go_2` the options are adapted according to possible adjustments in the first table.

I hope the explanations are clear and may help you.

```
library(shiny)
library(DataEditR)
library(tidyverse)

# Define UI for application
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("simple example")
  
  , actionButton("go_1", "Go")
  , br()
  , dataEditUI("table_1")
  , br()
  , textOutput("msg_1")
  , br()
  , actionButton("go_2", "Go to table 2")
  , br()
  , dataEditUI("table_2")
)

# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  table_1_df <- dataEditServer(
    "table_1"
    , data = eventReactive(input$go_1, {
      data.frame('id'=rep(c(1:5)))
    })
    , title = 'Table 1'
    , hide = TRUE
    , col_edit = FALSE
    , col_names = FALSE
    , col_readonly = c('id')
    , col_bind = c('last_name')
  )
  
  output$msg_1 <- renderPrint(  str(table_1_df())   )
  
  last_names_list <- eventReactive(input$go_2,{
    unique(table_1_df()$last_name)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$go_2,{
    last_names = last_names_list()
    table_2_df <- dataEditServer(
      "table_2"
      , data = eventReactive(input$go_2, {
        data.frame('id2'=rep(c(1:5)))
      })
      , title = 'Table 1'
      , hide = TRUE
      , col_edit = TRUE
      , col_names = FALSE
      , col_readonly = c('id2')
      , col_bind = c('last_name','first_name')
      , col_options = c(
        #'last_name' = list( c('a','b') )   
        'last_name' = list( last_names )
      )
    )
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: brilliant.  This solves the issue.   One follow-up question - If I want to use table_2_df in the next step, what's the best way to go about it?  My limited understanding is that the observedEvent will not let its results be used outside of its scope.   Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: that's right, I can't think of a quick solution to the problem using the DataEditR package either. But from my point of view you could easily solve all your problems by simply using the package rhandsontable, on which DataEditR is also based (see my following answer).